# Merge replication Locking on MSMerge_genHistory Table and lots of unhappy chickens

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I do contracting with about 10 chicken farms.  Each chicken has a GUID so we can track it through the entire life process (govt. requirement).  We have 2 million chickens in the tables at any one time.  One of my largest clients wants me to implement merge replication to another server so that they have 2 databases that look the same at any one time. SQL Server A will have data handling with users in the warehouses inputting data. SQL server B will have bulk data coming into it from grocery stores concerning our chickens and their sales information and will merge with Server A every 5 min.  If the GUIDs are the same the information with the latest updated date will win the Resolver.  We have about 1000 batch requests per second CPU is about 45% on a 16 Core Processor and 250GB of memory. On our Publication (server A) DB.  Server B looks the same except we have the bulk info come in 2 times a day with about 10000 DML queries.  We are trying to merge 900+ tables of which 45 of them are busy with Transactional processing all the time.   The 865 or so tables get updated about once a week. We are getting consistent  dead locks on our MergeGenHistory table. Look below.    We have also set our `generation_leveling_threshold` as below
`UPDATE sysmergepublications SET generation_leveling_threshold = 200000 WHERE NAME = ‘datbaseName’`.
Updating statistics on the merge replication tables every 5 min, right before the merge agent runs.

We have created a custom agent those settings are also below.  Everything not shown in the pick below is set at the default value.

[image: mergeHenHistoryPIC]

[image: MSMerge_ContentsPIC]

[image: Custom agent PIC]

Comment: I don't think Merge Replication is the appropriate approach here.  You may have better luck with a formal [Peer-to-Peer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/peer-to-peer-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-2017) setup due to the fact that you're already working with a transactional replication configuration.  A Peer-to-Peer setup would require enterprise edition though, but the benefit would be a single replication methodology as I think the mix/match approach in use is your biggest issue here.

Comment: thank you John  All tables above are involved in Merge Replication.  there is no Transactional Replication.  There is a lot of DML type activities going on in the 45 busy tables.   I will look into Peer-to-Peer.

Comment: Sorry, I read "Transactional Processing" as "Transactional Replication".  Either way, Peer-to-Peer is likely a more appropriate solution here.